# Running a standalone postgres instance alongside existing servers

Tags: postgresql

I'm developing an application that heavily relies on Postgres. Currently, users are required to have Postgres set up and place database credentials in a config file that my app reads.

There are a couple of issues with the approach which I am not entirely happy with:

- I can't dictate the version of Postgres to use (they may need a certain version for some other task)
- Users have to install a separate piece of software before they can use my application.
- They would need to provide database credentials to my app (which they may revoke later)
- Potentially issues with database name conflicts

Is it possible to run a standalone version of Postgres i.e running it from a folder and potentially alongside another version of Postgres on the same machine?

My current solution is to run it as a docker instance, this avoids any conflicts with data and permissions but does not solve the problem of needing users to install a separate piece of software first.

(I would have thought something like this would be possible for the people who develop Postgres - I can't imagine they constantly install and remove the software completely from their system in order to test things.)

Comment: Is your app totally standalone? Singleuser or multiuser? Do you want to allow users to manage their own Postgres install (eg with streaming replication)?

Comment: Yes, completely standalone and single user. From a users point of view, they never even need to know that Postgres is being used. There is never a need for a user to interact with the database directly, even actions like taking backups is handled by the app, which internally calls pg_dump